# How does findViewById() method work in activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I add a view to xml (layout) of my activity, it takes an id, so I can use that id in code of activity to recognize it and change my view if I like. Android make an R.class as an intermediate between my activity code an my layout(xml), so I use R.class for example:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

But how does android find it is a `TextView`? For example, if I write:

```
 Button b = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

I get an error. From where does it find I write it wrong?

I mean in R.class it define my id so android know a new id is defined in my xml, and I use it to return an object of View class or class extend View. But how does it find I am writing wrong and it is not a button, before I run the program (in compile time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio runs Android lint checks on your code, and there's the `WrongViewCast` check to detect such issues and report them as errors:

```
WrongViewCast
-------------
Summary: Mismatched view type

Priority: 9 / 10
Severity: Error
Category: Correctness

Keeps track of the view types associated with ids and if it finds a usage of
the id in the Java code it ensures that it is treated as the same type.
```

Source: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Answer (score 0):

If your view, that is returned by `findViewById(R.id.ID)`, doesn't cast to the field you're assigning the view to, your code won't even compile! Android Studio checks your assigned variables and tries to cast them in real-time, but if that fails, because you made a mistake, your Activity.java can't compile! This is just a way of how this IDE operates.

Some time ago, you needed to cast the view manually, like this:

`(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view)`

But this is not necessary anymore.